# MonoDroid Image Banding

Tags: android, image, bitmap, xamarin.android

Im having an issue with my backgrounds. I get horrible image banding when setting background images with gradients. When I set the background in my root layout I do it as follows:

```
        android:background="@drawable/GradientImage"
```

I have also tried setting the background of my root layout in the code (after removing background from axml):

```
        Window.SetFormat(Android.Graphics.Format.Rgbx8888); 
        Window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Dither); 

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        options.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888; 
        Bitmap gradient = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Background_640,options); 
        sv.SetBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(gradient));
```

This is done in OnCreate and unfortunately does not fix the issue,

Has anyone ever came across this issue? Does anyone now how to fix this.

Comment: Usually banding is due to insufficient color resolution on either the bitmap or the canvas you're drawing the image to. Check the bitdepth on both and set something higher - that might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me (in onCreate())

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
```

Also, when using PNG images, make sure they are using 32-bit color depth,
because some image editing programs save them as 24-bit by default.
For example, in GIMP, you can force the PNG image to be saved as 32-bit
by adding alpha channel.

Comment: This page also covers this where different modes are used and compares the results: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/